# CSS div flexible 3-row layout

Tags: css

I have made a [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/suhasi/edit?html,css,output) here to demonstrate what I want to achieve. I had achieved with `display: flex` but unfortunately it does not work well with IE11 and Opera.

I want a cross browser CSS solution such that, `#row_1` has a `max-height` of `400px` and `min-height` of `0`.

When `#row_1` has no content, `#row_2` should take up all height in `#container`

When `#row_1` has content, `#row_2` should resize such that `#row_1` has content and `#row_2` fills the height of container.

> `row_1` can have a `max-height: 400px`, `min-height: 0`
>
> `row_2` can have a `max-height: #container - #row_1` and `min-height: 500px`

```
<div id="header"><h1>Height 80px</h1></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="row_1">
  Here can be something or nothing at all<br>
</div>
<div id="row_2">this should fill the all available height of parent div</div>
```

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div#header {
  background: red;
  height: 80px;
}

div#container {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

div#row_1 {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

div#row_2 {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: It is working fine. And what is meaning of `min-height:0` it is by default.

Comment: @ketan i meant to not take any space. its not working fine, the map should take up all available height

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I tried to get around this problem with javascript but then ran into another problem i.e. different browsers would respond to #row_1 height differently

Answer (score 0):

Configure the style properties for the element h1.

```
div#header h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: this does not solves the problem of making the div with map fill the all available height

Comment: remove the <br> inner div "row_1": Here can be something or nothing at all<br>

Comment: i had put that only for demo